# Populate table in Cognos report studio

Tags: cognos

I want to populate a table item within page Explorer in a report I'm working on.
I then want to use a text item with a vlookup command to reference this data in my final excel based output.

I've created a new page within page explorer, and added a table item from the toolbox, but I can't edit what's in there.  Ideally, I'd like to copy and paste data from another spreadsheet into this table.

Thanks,
Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

Report Studio's **Table elements** are layout helpers, what you are probably looking for is a **List element** which holds a grid or spreadsheet of data.

That said, you can't simply edit/hardcode values in List elements in Report Studio, they need to be sourced from a Query object that is pulling data from a database. (Hint: You can tell what Query a List element is connected to by right-clicking and choosing "Go To Query".)

There are tricks to hard code values by sourcing from SQL-based Query subjects, but what you might be looking for in the long-term is the Cognos feature "External Data" which, if your administrators allow it, can link to files on your desktop so that you can combine data from your database with data in a local Excel document.

Search for "Working with your External Data" or reference the link below to print the applicable section of the Report Studio User Guide for v10.2 version of IBM Cognos BI.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r2m0/advanced/print.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.2.0.doc/c_rs_persdat.html?path=3_5_14&anchor=rs_persdat&isSelectedTopicPrint=true